# How is this property of an object a different value in these two cases?

Tags: python

How is the property of lists(`Case 1`) called that lets the output of `print y` be different from `Case 2`?

```
# Case 1: using a list as value
>>> x = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> y = x
>>> x[0] = "four"
>>> print x
["four", "two", "three"]
>>> print y
["four", "two", "three"]

# Case 2: using an integer as value
>>> x = 3
>>> y = x
>>> x = x + 1
>>> print x
4
>>> print y
3
```

**Edit**:

To show that this behavior has nothing to do with lists being mutable and strings not, instead of Case 2, the following case could have been given instead:

```
>>> x = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> y = x
>>> x = x + ["four", "five"]
>>> print x
["four", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
>>> print y
["four", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: Please make the title of your question readable. Avoid putting code in there, better try to summarize your question.

Comment: What _would_ be a good title for this question, if someone doesn't know about references vs. values?

Comment: Exactly, if you don't know the name of the property how would you explain it Ivaylo?

Comment: About the change someone made in the title: it may be easier to read but it's less descriptive. I don't really see this as an improvement. If someone had the same question as me, I don't see how that title would ever lead him to this thread. So the question will be easily duplicated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between two snippets is

```
>>> x[0] = "four"
```

vs

```
>>> x = x + 1
```

In the first case, you *modify* an existing object, in the second you *create* a new one. So the first snippet has one object and two names, x and y, referring to it, in the second snippet there are two objects. Note that this has nothing to do with *mutability* of lists (and *immutability* of ints), you could have written the second snippet as

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x 
x = x + [4]
```

and get essentially the same result (=two distinct objects).

Comment: So the accepted answer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797114/python-references) is wrong then? The answerer says it is because of mutability.

Comment: @Bentley4: yes, it's wrong.

Comment: Unless i misunderstand the return value of id(x), x = x + [4] seemingly creates a new object, while x += [4] does not. Amazing.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha: yes, for lists add != iadd, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9766387/989121