# Behaviour of dictionary.append in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing some code where my highest aim is, to deliver some information in json format. I want to display servernames and serverurls like this: ( My aim is not the pretty print but I just displayed it like this, so it is more obvious )

```
{
 "server": [
            { "name" : "some_server_name", "url" : "some_server_url" }
            { "name" : "another_server_name", "url" : "another_server_url" }
           ]
}
```

I got now two lists, one with the servernames and the other with serverulrs. I iterate over the names and then access to the matching url. After that is done I want to append it to a dictionary. When I got this dictionary. I want to append this to my json_dict. I created that dict because I have two other lists which I want to display too in my json information. ( You can ignore rdp and cert because they are already displayed correctly )

```
def build_dict(server_name, server_url, rdp, cert):
        json_dict = defaultdict(list)
        server_dict = {}

        if server_name and server_url:
                for i, iter_name in enumerate(server_name):
                        server_dict.update( name = iter_name, url = server_url[i] )
                        json_dict['server'].append(server_dict)
        if rdp:
                for iter_rdp in rdp:
                        json_dict['config'].append(iter_rdp)
        if cert:
                for iter_cert in cert:
                        json_dict['cert'].append(iter_cert)

        return json_dict
```

The entries of my servernames list:

> [u'123name', u'qwer123']

And the entries of my serverurls list:

> [u'123url', u'qwer123']

Unfortunately the final output looks like this:

```
{"cert": ["123url", "123123", "123123123"],
 "config": ["123rdp", "123123", "123123123"],
  "server": [
             {"url": "qwer123", "name": "qwer123"},
             {"url": "qwer123", "name": "qwer123"}
             ]
}
```

You can ignore cert and config because this already works as expected. I just don't understand why I have:

```
{"url": "qwer123", "name": "qwer123"},
{"url": "qwer123", "name": "qwer123"}
```

And not:

```
{"url": "123name", "name": "123url"},
{"url": "qwer123", "name": "qwer123"}
```

as output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797114/python-references)

Comment: Can you guys please as well explain the downvote :) ? I want my question to be as good as possible

Comment: Your problem is possibly outside the posted code, can you change it to show how your calling build_dict. I mean, are you certain your not calling it with the same parameters?

Comment: Move `server_dict = {}` *inside* the `for` loop (or just replace the `update` with `server_dict = dict(name=iter_name, url=server_url[i])`).

Comment: you saved my life jon... Now that I see that, it is obvious ... I tried to figure it out for 1 whole day now >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe stated, you have your `server_dict` at the wrong place. You should consider putting it in your for loop, so you just update the two entries which you recently received through your for loop.

```
if server_name and server_url:
    for i, iter_name in enumerate(server_name):
        server_dict = dict( name = iter_name, url = server_url[i] )
        json_dict['server'].append(server_dict)
```

Comment: The line `server_dict = {}` is redundant here.