# List B append in list A - but when B removed A also empty

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pointers, reference

I just realized now that when I append a list to another list and I delete this appended list, the list also wont be in the other list.
Makes maybe sense, because appending a list to somewhere else is just a reference. So when I'm using something like this:

```
B[:] = []
```

Then it will be gone from everywhere. How can I avoid this issue? Using **copy**? My problem is that I'm collecting lists in a list and at some point I'm adding this whole thing to another list - after that I would like to make the added list empty to use it to adding new data to it.

Comment: what you mean by :  *when I'm using something like this:`B[:] = []`
Then it will be gone from everywhere* ?

Comment: @Kasra: the list is empty, and its also not in the other list where it was appended

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797114/python-references)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiet way will be:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = ['k']
>>> a.append(list(b))
>>> b[:] = []
>>> b
11: []
>>> a
12: [['k']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = list()
>>> b.append(a[:])
>>> a = []
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the `List` in another object and should operate then:-

```
a, b = range(10), []
c = a[:]
b.append(c)
a[:] = []
```