# Top 3 questions to test someones Python level, what would they be?

Tags: python

If you had to **judge someones level of Python understand in just 3 questions**, what would you ask?

Comment: Here's one: If a python has started constricting itself around your body, what's the best way to get it to stop?

Comment: Ooh Ooh! "Are pythons poisonous?"

Comment: If you can wait a day, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related goes into public beta tomorrow. Perfect place for this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much the same as for any language.

- What projects have you done with Python?
- What is your favorite Python reference?
- Have you worked with other people on code written in Python?

That's how I would judge. If I wanted to test, it would depend on whether I were looking for someone to write in 2.x or 3.x. Since I'm familiar with the 2.x stuff...

- How would you create a list containing the result of [insert operation] on another list?
- How would you do the above if you cared about memory usage?
- What tool do you use to debug your Python code?

CW'd because the question should be.

Answer (score 1):

1. Explain generators.
2. Write unit tests for `<important-piece-of-code>`.
3. Who is Alex Martelli?