# C++ | Progresssion Path

Tags: c++

I know the `basic OOP-related topics`, `RTTI, Templates`. Reverting back from `Java' Collection Framework`, I tried to find such collections in `C++` and found `STL`, and am trying to use it in my projects (although I don't know them in and out). I searched and found recommendations for books like `Accelerated C++, Effective and More Effective C++`.

But I am not sure what should be my progression path. I am looking for something like this -- [Python-Progression Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru):

> ```
> def apprentice():
>   read(diveintopython)
>   experiment(interpreter)
>   read(python_tutorial)
>   experiment(interpreter, modules/files)
>   watch(pycon)
>
> def master():
>   refer(python-essential-reference)
>   refer(PEPs/language reference)
>   experiment()
>   read(good_python_code) # Eg. twisted, other libraries
>   write(basic_library)   # reinvent wheel and compare to existing wheels
>   if have_interesting_ideas:
>      give_talk(pycon)
>
> def guru():
>   pass # Not qualified to comment. Fix the GIL perhaps?
> ```
>
> 1. Discover [list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python)
> 2. Discover [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Generators)
> 3. Incorporate [map, reduce, filter, iter, range, xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) often into your code
> 4. Discover [Decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)
> 5. Write recursive functions, a lot
> 6. Discover [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and [functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html)
> 7. Read [Real World Haskell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514980)
> 8. Rewrite all your old Python code with tons of higher order functions, recursion, and whatnot.
> 9. Annoy your cubicle mates every time they present you with a Python class.  Claim it could be "better" implemented as a dictionary
>      plus some functions.  Embrace functional programming.
> 10. Rediscover the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Python) pattern and then [all those things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) from imperative code you tried so hard to forget after
>       Haskell.
> 11. Find a balance.

Comment: Although you have C++ in the question title and a c++ tag, there doesn't appear to be anything to do with C++ in the question. Come to think of it, what is the question?

Comment: The implied question is "What is the equivalent of this list for students of C++?"

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I updated my question.

Comment: Oh god, why did you post a screenshot of some blurry text, when you could have just shown us the raw text?

Comment: @jaif: okay! I changed to text (from screenshot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a tough question, because what you really need is becoming good at what you do, and thus no authoritative list exists.

That being said...

- Read `Effective C++` by Meyers and `C++ Coding Standards` by Sutter, you're not likely to understand everything if you're a beginner, so re-read them from time to time (it's also a good vaccine)
- Time to introduce the STL (it's an amazing little pearl), learn to use its algorithms instead of hand-crafting everything, if possible jump straight to the C++0x version
- Incorporate Boost into the mix, softly at first: `boost::optional`, `boost::variant`, `boost::lexical_cast`, `boost::numeric_cast` make your code safer and more idiomatic. Also poke the Boost String Algorithms library.
- Template Meta Programming and Boost.MPL are next: C++ Template Meta Programming by Abrahams Gurtovoy will help there. You might have to leverage Boost.Preprocessor for some template stuff.
- Learn more Boost Libraries, it's a gigormous repository and it's amazing all the libraries there are.

I am still at that last part myself, so cannot comment on going further :)

At each step, you should write a lot of code, reading isn't sufficient, you need to experiment. Programming is not just technic, the architectural part of the program is extremely important in the field.

Oh and try and join (if only to read) an open-source project, nothing beats writing code and it's better when someone else reviews it :)

Answer (score 0):

First get really good with C. I recommend "Deep C Secrets" by Peter van der Linden.

Get a copy of "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers, and commit it's advice to memory ("More Effective C++" is also pretty good).

Read "Advanced C++" by Coplien.

Read the [The C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/).

Read "The C++ Programming Language" by Stroustrup at this point.

Comment: Getting good with C may actually teach you bad habits to be avoided in C++.

Comment: @Mark B: Agreed. I would definitely not teach prospective C++ students C habits.

Comment: It's good to have C habits to fall back on when you discover that some of the C++ stuff is horribly slow.

Comment: @kotlinski: yes and no, there are fast typesafe C++ libraries, use them :)

Comment: I stand by my original statement. C will give you a good perspective on the hardware. Also, it is possible to write good C. I agree that C may instill some bad habits, but exposure to it I think will make you more pragmatic, and less ideological.