# Why claim a python class could be "better" implemented as a dictionary plus some functions?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I saw this instruction in an answer to the question [Python progression path - From apprentice to guru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576240/108176).

> 9. Annoy your cubicle mates every time they present you with a Python class. Claim it could be "better" implemented as a dictionary plus some functions. Embrace functional programming.

But I don't understand this. What does this do with functional programming?

Comment: Most of these recommendations are quite tongue-in-cheek.  In principle, every class can be implemented as a set of functions, always passing a dictionary as the first parameter.  (You lose dynamic polymorphism, of course.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: You can have your polymorphism, just put the functions in the dicts. Then just call `aDict['aMethodName'](aDict, ...)` and bang, you have polymorphism.

Comment: You need to read Real World Haskell before you can proceed to level 9 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is in the "Python progression path" is that it reflects a realization that Python classes are just syntactic sugar for functions and dicts, and that by using functions and dicts directly, one needs fewer elements of the language, thereby making one's programs more "pure."

Of course this is utterly misguided, which is why it is funny. Or maybe I just haven't reached enlightenment yet?

Answer (score 3):

It means that:

```
class A:
    def __init__(this):
        this.count = 0
    def bump(this):
        this.count += 1

a = A()
a.bump()
```

can be replaced by something along the lines of:

```
def constructA():
    return {'count':0}

def bumpA(anA):
    anA['count'] += 1

a = constructA()
bumpA(a)
```

or, even more functional style,  avoid side effects by returning a copy:

```
def bumpedA(anA):
    newA = {'count': (anA['count'] + 1 )}
    return newA

a = constructA()
a = bumpedA(a)
```

This is the basic pattern - you can get polymorphism by putting the methods in the dictionary itself (javascript-style) and generally reconstruct the whole Python object system using dicts and functions.

Comment: Are there any advantages to this?

Comment: @RustyFluff: Hard question, as it is a matter of taste (to a degree at least.) In Python, in general - no, unless you have a very specific reason to do so. Maybe a quick-and-dirty translation of a Javascript program. Outside Python - maybe check Clojure's polymorphism and see how you like it. The advantage is the immutability although again it's a matter of taste.