# Multi-Referenced Nested Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was looking at this guy's post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573965/1959054

He was talking about testing people's Python proficiency by asking them the outputs of the following code:

```
x = 42
y = x
x = x+1
print x
print y

x = [1,2,3]
y = x
x[0]=4
print x
print y
```

I predicted those two outputs successfully, having just read about similar scenarios with mutable lists and immutable strings in a book. Then he gave this example:

```
x = ["foo",[1,2,3],10.4]
y = list(x)
y[0] = 'foooooo'
y[1][0] = 4
print x
print y
```

This left me very confused. You see, I predicted that `x` would print as `["foo",[1,2,3],10.4]` and `y` would print as `["foooooo",[4,2,3],10.4]`.

`x` actually printed as `["foo",[4,2,3],10.4]`, meaning that, even though the outside list was referencing different `list` objects, the inner list at `x[1]` and `y[1]` was still referencing the same object.

I hadn't come across this before.

My primary question is, if you want to make `y` equivalent to `x`, but not reference the same list, and ALSO make sure any nested lists aren't referencing the same lists as well, how do you do that? `y = list(x)` seems to only handle the outer list.

My secondary question is just to get any help conceptually understanding why this works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is answered by `copy.deepcopy()`, which ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)):

> constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

```
from copy import deepcopy
y = deepcopy(x)
```

As to why this happens, the standard list construction from `list()` (and the common `slice` copy `x[:]`) creates only a shallow copy, i.e. (docs again, emphasis mine):

> constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts **references** into it to the objects found in the original.

Comment: Thanks, I think you've hit the nail on the head for me.