# What I do next with python?

Tags: python

I have only 4-5 months of coding in Python.I finished http://codecademy.com/ track , I finished to read the book: "Learn Python by hard way", I almost finished a Python course on EDX and I did some projects(console applications and some GUI). Now, i don't know how to continue, but i want to improve my knowledge in programming.

Who can tell me some suggestions about how i can continue in Python, or some projects idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [help/dont-ask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can..

- Take a look at other Python projects (for example at [Github](https://github.com/), learn from it, why/how it works (or perhaps find some bugs and contribute back - perhaps you have to learn Git first before you can do that, which I strongly recommend)
- Why not start a web project? You can use a [django web framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to show something fancy to the world (a simple game written in Python for example)
- Design some useful software you probably need it now or in the near future
- Or just learn other languages, like Haskell, which is **completely** different from other, courrant programming languages
- ...

Answer (score -1):

Here's some ideas for learning more about Python: do some searches like 'python projects', 'small python projects', 'learning python', 'more advanced python', ...; look through the Python library code (it's part of your Python install, including source code) and try on your own to write (simplified) versions of the classes that interest your; [look at recipes in ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/search/recipes/) and other Python recipes/solutions/implementations sites (more searching). Reading other people's code (especially code that you find challenging to understand) is a great way to learn quickly. Python makes it easy to do hands-on experimentation so do lots of that. And of course - meander around StackOverflow...