# New to python and programming in general, need help editing a variable in terms of itself

Tags: python

When I put this in it brings up an error and I'd like some help finding out what I did wrong.

```
x = 0

def func(var):  
    if var = True:  
        x = x - 1
    else:
        pass
```

The error comes from x = x - 1, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share your error message?

Comment: and **what** error? "it brings up an error" is not helpful -- we aren't mind readers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python progression path - From apprentice to guru](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually from the line before. You are confusing `=` (assignment operator) with the `==` (comparison operator). The correct code is as follows:

```
def func(var):
    global x
    if var == True:  
        x -= 1         #also you can simply do it as x -= 1 instead of x = x - 1
    else:
        pass
```

Finally, there is really no point in having `else: pass` since you're not doing anything in there. Just shorten your code to:

```
def func(var):
    global x
    if var == True:
        x -= 1
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `x` inside the scope of the function you have to tell the compiler where to find `x`
so change your code to:

```
x = 0
def func(var):  
    if var == True:
        global x  # look for x outside the scope of the function
        x = x - 1
    else:
        pass
```

Also it's nice to have a return into functions so I propose:

```
x = 0
def func(var):  
    if var == True:
        global x  # look for x outside the scope of the function
        x = x - 1
    return None  # or -> return x (to return the value of x)
```

Comment: there is no reason to return None, python returns None by default.  If you need an early return with no value just return with no value, this is python's equivalent of a void function. Although it not good for chaining good python style discourages functions that mutate and return values.

Comment: Thanks for helping an idiot like me.

Answer (score 0):

First you put an assignment operator `=` instead of the equals operator `==`

```
x = 0

def func(var):  
    if var == True:  
        x = x - 1
    else:
        pass
```

Second never check if expressions/values are equal(==) to  `True` /`False` especially in python. Just give a statement/variable that is `True` or truthy/`False` or falsey. In python None(null) empty collections such as [], 0, 0.0, timedelta of zero, and `False` are falsey and just about everything else is truthy. To test this for yourself just try passing the value or expression to the bool function to see if it returns `True` or `False`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing for more info.

```
x = 0

def func(var):  
    if var:  
        x = x - 1
    else:
        pass
```

Third you can lookup but not reassign a variable declared in the same module
outside the function. unless you declare it global. so you can print without global

```
x = 0

def func(var):  
    if var:
        print x
```

but not reassign it. Also you don't need a else branch or return statement(python defaults to returning None), so it's just

```
x = 0

def func(var):  
    if var:
        global x  
        x = x - 1
```