# Write to the console or to file python

Tags: python, file-io, io, console

I have a function:

```
def hello_world(output):
    output.write("Hello World")
```

And would like to pass these to it:

```
file = io.open("myfile.txt", "w")
hello_world(file)
hello_world(sys.stdout)
```

I don't know if it is right this way. I also get `NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined`
How would you do what I would like to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add:

```
import sys
```

to the top of your file

Answer (score 2):

> NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined

Fixed by `import sys` at the top of your python file

As an aside, [it's a horrible idea to have variables named `file` or `list` or `dict` or pretty much any default type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710405/198633).

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
import sys
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to `import sys`

[sys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) is the "System-specific parameters and functions" module of python - [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).

what this does is get the system specific standard out pipe for the python file to output *to*. as in a stream it can write to :).

File and `sys.stdout`, `sys.stdin` and `sys.stderr` are all just streams to write to.

In general if it says `NameError` you either forgot to import something or you didn't define something correctly :)

you probably want to rewrite that as opened_file or the like, `File` and some other words similar like if you did `random = 3` are never good to address because they are used as names of various Python objects or internals - and you want to make sure you don't have collisions even though Python is supposed to resolve these cleverly :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `sys` module:

```
import sys
```

Then you can use `sys.stdout` afterwards.